# Some links and form in firefox not clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, hyperlink

I have a strange issue in Firefox. The text-links in my content and the form are not clickable. I tried to fix the issue by using z-index for the affected elements but this did not work. I also checked if there are any elements covering the affected areas, but I could not  find anything. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Some affected text-links here (text-blocks next to the images): [click](http://kazakhstan.cargobull-events.com/)

The form: [click](http://kazakhstan.cargobull-events.com/registration/)

Thank you vey much!

Comment: Could you share the form and js code snippet where form is getting failed?

Comment: Thank you! The forms were built with formidable-plugin (https://formidableforms.com/). I used this plugin many times and never had some issues with it. Also the issue is still there on pages that does not have any form inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a problem in your following class.
div:not(.autoGrid-lightbox) *

you are using some wordpress or jquery plugin which is creating this mess.

Add this in your CSS

```
div:not(.autoGrid-lightbox) * {
 webkit-transform-style: none !important;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi! Thank you... I added this to the css but unfortunately it still does not work. Any more ideas?

Comment: The problem is with css of your site. it has some additional properties.  I disabled the properties to make the link working

Comment: Could you please tell me which properties you disabled? Thank you! :-)

Comment: Found it! I accidently had a `z-index:-2;` in the class `.content-row` that caused the issue... Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Glad you find it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday but without looking over your code I don't know how much help I can be.

You could try some jQuery in order to look for the link. It will look something like this.

```
 $('.yourClass').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 
 window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: I tried the jQuery thing an it is not working. What I see now is when I inspect the links with the developer-tools it always detects an outer wrapper of a larger area (for example the body or the .content-container... Could this cause the issue and does anyone know how to fix?